# How to analyse a French phone number according to E.164

Tags: phone-number

From the E.164 schema below, how should I understand a French phone number like `+33712345678` or `0712345678` when calling from France ?

Which part is TC, CC, NSN, NDC and SN ?

[image]

Is the analyse below correct ?

(**updated** as per @`Lewis Kelsey`'s answer)

1. **Public Line Prefix**: *none*
2. **TC** - International Prefix, **T**runk **C**ode**:

   - International Dialing Prefix: `+` (equivalent to 00 from France)
   - **CC** - **C**ountry **C**alling Code: `33`
   - National Access Code: `0`
3. **NSN**:

   - **NDC** - **N**ational **D**estination **C**ode: `07`
   - **SN** - **S**ubscriber's **N**umber: `12345678` (Base Number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public Line Prefix not sure what this is, but it's not part of the number

The International Dialing Prefix (IDD) or International access code is `00` if you are calling from france. `+` means add the International Dialing Prefix of the country you are calling from, which is `00`

Country code is `33`

National Access Code (aka. NDD prefix aka. the [national trunk prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_prefix)): This is the `0` part of `07` i.e. it's when you make a national call and use `0` instead of `0033`

NDC - National Destination Code / Area Code / STD : `07`, includes the NAC `0`, which is replaced with the international prefix and country code if called from another country

Subscriber's Number: `12345678`, which comprises a base number and DID extension if it belongs to a business